# C++ calls Cython and passes a string

Tags: c++, string, cython

i provide a cython function to my `C++` code for printing:

```
cdef public bint prettyPrint(const string cppString):
    print(cppString.decode('UTF-8')
    return True
```

In my `C++`header, i have defined the prototype:

```
bool prettyPrint(const string& cppString);
```

This works perfect!
Interestingly, it works also if i define (mind the reference):

```
cdef public bint prettyPrint(const string &cppString):
    print(cppString.decode('UTF-8')
    return True
```

but this is clearly slower! Why is that and what is the difference between both variants? Thank you!

Comment: Why is the second version "clearly slower"? Did you measure it?

Comment: Measurement is not necessary in my case, i have an mathematical routine which calls these functions quite often for logging and the total runtime increased by factor 5 or more. Despite the real complexity should be the mathematical computations.. .

Comment: Ok, so you did measure it. That counts as measured. To be honest, that is the most surprising part of it; I wouldn't expect version taking a const reference being slower.

Comment: Does this actually work (ignoring the obvious missing bracket)? The C++ string doesn't have a function `decode` I'd be very surprised if you could get away without a type conversion.

Comment: In fact I can confirm that this doesn't compile with Cython...

Comment: Sry, the decode was a mistake, you are right! Try it without decode(), the phenomenon remains the same in my case (and compiles).

Comment: On gcc (with the default settings from `setup.py` which look to be `-O2` plus some other stuff) the assembly code for the two functions looks identical to me. I think that's all I can contribute here though.